# Irrklang Frequency Spectrum with C++

Tags: c++, audio, frequency-analysis, irrklang

As someone with absolutely no experience in how audio works, I'm want to make a real-time frequency spectrum with audio that I'm currently playing through irrklang.

Ideally, I would like to have db values of different frequencies in an array of some sort.

I've read some of the other questions related to this, however none of them seem to deal specifically with implementing a frequency spectrum with irrklang.

What I have in irrklang:

```
ISound* sndA = engine->play2D(a.c_str(), true, false, true, ESM_NO_STREAMING);
```

Comment: I don't think irrKlang will help you here. You need to load the file into some simple pcm format (which irrKlang seems to only do internally and not expose to you). Then you need to run it through some form of Fourier Transformations (most likely just just some fft lib), then you can read out the amplitudes for the individual frequencies.

Comment: @PeterT irrklang exposes raw decoded PCM data through `getSampleData()`, which I have successfully gotten working. Any fft libs to recommend for a noob? (Really good documentation with sample code would be nice)